# how to translate the function INDEX(MATCH...to VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the index function and match to find a value in a table

In Excel I use the following function:

`=INDEX('Mi Guia.xls'!STACKED;MATCH(I12;PUERTO;0);MATCH(I10;TARJETA;0))`

but I don't know how to apply it on vba so I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (may need some slight adjustments since we can't see the definitions for your named ranges)

```
Dim m1, m2

m1 = Application.Match(Range("I12").Value,Range("PUERTO"), 0)
m2 = Application.Match(Range("I10").Value,Range("TARJETA"), 0)

if not iserror(m1) and not iserror(m2) then
    debug.print workbooks("Mi Guia.xls").Range("STACKED").cells(m1, m2).Value
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do it. From the **cleanest** one:

- rewriting the formula using `WorksheetFunction.Index` and `WorksheetFunction.Match`

  - [WorksheetFunction.Match() Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match)

To the **dirtiest** one:

- put the formula in Excel and translate it to a string. Then concatenate the string and change the string, containing variables. This is what could be used. Select the cell with the formula and run this:

---

```
Public Sub PrintMeUsefulFormula()

    Dim selectedFormula  As String
    Dim parenthesis  As String

    parenthesis = """"

    selectedFormula = Selection.Formula
    selectedFormula = Replace(selectedFormula, """", """""")

    selectedFormula = parenthesis & selectedFormula & parenthesis
    Debug.Print selectedFormula

End Sub
```

---

Then take the printed string in the immediate window and refer it to a cell like this:

```
Worksheets(1).Range("A5").Formula = printedString
```

If the string looks like this: `"=INDEX(A1:J5,MATCH(1,E1:E5),MATCH(3,A3:J3))"` and you need to change the `3` of the second match with a variable `a`, then something like this works:

```
ws.Range("A5").Formula = "=INDEX(A1:J5,MATCH(1,E1:E5),MATCH(" & a & ",A3:J3))"
```